# How to delay a function returning a value before response from database?

Tags: javascript, database, function, asynchronous, redis

I have a function which modifies a variable as per response from database.

```
function f () {
     let x = { }; 

     redis.get ("key1").then ( value => x.prop1 = value);

     redis.get ("key2").then ( value => x.prop2 = value);

     return x;
}
```

This is my code roughly. It is actually in a for loop, using node-redis.

I have multiple calls to Redis. I add the data from Redis to a new object and return the object.

**PROBLEM:** function `f ()` is returning an empty object every time I call it.

How do I wait for all Redis promises to resolve before returning the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are not waiting for redis values to resolve before you are returning `x`. You should enclose it in `async-await` for that.

Also, note that invoking `f()` will not return the value directly, it will return a `promise`.

```
async function f () { // note async
     let x = { }; 

     await redis.get ("key1").then ( value => x.prop1 = value); // note await

     await redis.get ("key2").then ( value => x.prop2 = value);

     return x;
}
```

You can then use it like `f().then(console.log)`

Example:

```js
//var Promise = require('bluebird')
console.log("started");
var f = async function() {
    return { 
      prop1: await Promise.delay(3000).then(_ => 3),
      prop2: await Promise.delay(2000).then(_ => 4)
    }
}

f().then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.js"></script>
```

which can also be simplified to:

```
async function f () {
     let x = { }; 

     return { prop1: await redis.get('key1'), prop2: await redis.get('key2') }  
}
```

**Edit**: On thinking about this more, I think you should just rather move away from async-await for this use-case, and instead use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Reason - those two redis `get` operations can happen concurrently and shouldn't wait for it's turn. Using `await` will stall the invocation of second redis call. Try running the example snippet above, and you will notice how the result comes in total 5s (3 + 2), while it easily come in ~3s.

`Promise.all` accepts a bunch of promises and waits for all of them to resolve before invoking it's resolution.

```js
console.log("started");
var f = function() {
    var x = {}
    var promises = [
        Promise.delay(3000).then(_ => { x.prop1 = 3 }),
        Promise.delay(2000).then(_ => { x.prop2 = 4 })
    ]
    // wait for all of above to resolve and then resolve with `x`
    return Promise.all(promises).then(_ => x)
}

f().then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.js"></script>
```

^ Try running this snippet now and note the difference in time.

Comment: @JonasLochmann dude. relax. I just wanted to post answer for my own, not to make you happy. If I wanted to actually copy your answer, I would have copied it without `x`. If I wanted to copy your answer, I wouldn't have cared to experiment on my own and add some example which actually makes sense.

Comment: Guys please don't fight... Thank you both for your efforts.

Comment: @Vikirnt No. I'm not even taking this as fight. by the way, I just edited my answer to add a **better** alternative which should actually make sense with your use-case. May be helpful for your knowledge and journey with promises :)

Comment: @jonas lochmann you really think that you can declare ownership for such a simple snippet?! This answer is way better as it includes a proper explanation.

Comment: Promise.all is fantastic. Thanks!